# Cannot create AVD in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I cant create an AVD in eclipse, and whenever I try the ok button doesn't allow me to click on it. I was looking at other solutions but those solutions are still not working. please help

Comment: check sdk manager and install API 19. might help

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are leaving some mandatory field while creating AVD thEn a message will appear at the bottom and will not allow you to create AVD . see What is the message (AS POINTED OUT IN THE BELOW SCREENSHOT) and resolve accordingly

[image]

see What is the message here and resolve accordingly